# binding the xml to same code page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to bind a XML page to same underlying code page.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Foreground="Transparent" Checked="ToggleSwitch_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=LockSetting, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock Text="locks or unlocks your calender" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="statusBox" Text="{Binding stat1}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
```

I have set the data context as

```
stat1 = "abn";
InitializeComponent();

aps = this.Resources["appSettings"] as AppSettings;
this.colorpicker.Color = Color.FromArgb(aps.ASetting, aps.RSetting, aps.GSetting, aps.BSetting);
ContentPanel.DataContext = this;
```

But this is not working at all. Any help will be good.

Comment: Your problem definition is not clear. What is not working?

Comment: the textbox is not showing the data

Comment: have you tried binding text of textbox to a property

Comment: i tried but failed. kindly explain it for me that how can i achieve this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `ContentPanel.DataContext = this` it implies in this case that the Code-behind of the XAML would be providing context for the data binding. More specifically, when you write `{Binding sta1}` in the XAML, sta1 must be a property in the code behind. That is, sta1 should be something like that:

```
public String sta1 { get; set; }
```